# Hide keyboard programmatically in MonoDroid

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I am using the following code to detect the user pressing Return on the keyboard:

```
EditText etMyEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etMyEditText);
etMyEditText.KeyPress += (intentSender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
};
```

But I want to dismiss the keyboard after they press the return key.

Can anyone shed some light on how to do this?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Second line, should `etMyEditText` be `etCityTownZip`?

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 6):

This piece of code will close soft keyboard programmatically.

```
InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) GetSystemService(InputMethodService);
manager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(etMyEditText.WindowToken, 0);
```

The second parameter passing to `manager.HideSoftInputFromWindow` is a [`flag`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#hideSoftInputFromWindow%28android.os.IBinder,%20int%29) which

> Provides additional operating flags. Currently may be 0 or have the [HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY) bit set.